# How to keep Hollandaise sauce from "setting" before serving

Tags: hollandaise

I have been making Hollandaise sauce using a Gordon Ramsey recipe (https://youtu.be/vyd6PluAH3k); and while it is good and tasty, if I don't make it as the very last thing it seems to "set" or become more like scrambled eggs if I leave it, even for just a minute or so.

The recipe above is basically egg yolks, white wine vinegar, mix, put over roiling water, whisk until thickened, add butter, whisk, add salt/pepper/lemon, serve.

I have tried:

-Reducing the heat while whisking and turning it off completely

-Putting just the bowl aside (not over the hot water)

-Putting the bowl in cold water (Not ice water, just cold tap water)

In all these cases, the sauce seems to set or keep cooking and becomes scrambled eggs. As I'm writing this, I realise that I haven't tried putting it in a fresh bowl, which I guess I will try next.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I can do to keep my Hollandaise from setting? Am I making it wrong?

Comment: In Good Eats, Alton Brown recommended putting it in a thermos to keep warm (I believe he had heated it with hot water first)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I guess I didn't make it clear, but this is only for the duration of finishing breakfast.

I have found that if I make the hollandaise sauce last, the other breakfast items go cold :-/